# WordPress Theme change metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I edit the Php file for a Wordpress theme (shape - downloaded from themeshaper.com) to  change the metadata.

for example current php file below displays the meta of a normal post like this:
[image]

for example instead of [avatar] [author] written on [date] like in the image above, I would like to change to Posted on [date] by [author].

Php File (content.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Shape
 * @since Shape 1.0
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <!-- header content -->
        <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'shape' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1><?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php shape_posted_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?><!-- end header content -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header --><?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'shape' ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'shape' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?> <footer class="entry-meta">
        <!-- footer content -->
        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : // Hide category and tag text for pages on Search ?>
            <?php
                /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
                $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'shape' ) );
                if ( $categories_list && shape_categorized_blog() ) :
            ?>
            <span class="cat-links">
                <?php printf( __( 'Posted in %1$s', 'shape' ), $categories_list ); ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif; // End if categories ?>        <?php endif; // End if 'post' == get_post_type() ?>     <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : // Hide category and tag text for pages on Search ?>
            <?php
                /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
                $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'shape' ) );
                if ( $tags_list ) :
            ?>
            <span class="sep"> | </span>
            <span class="tag-links">
                <?php printf( __( 'Tagged %1$s', 'shape' ), $tags_list ); ?>
            </span>
            <?php endif; // End if $tags_list ?>
        <?php endif; // End if 'post' == get_post_type() ?><div style="float:right;"><?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) ) : ?>
        <span class="sep"> | </span>
        <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'shape' ), __( '1 Comment', 'shape' ), __( '% Comments', 'shape' ) ); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?></div><!-- end footer content -->
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'shape' ), '<span class="sep"> | </span><span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

contnet-aside php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying posts in the Aside post format
 * @package Shape
 * @since Shape 2.0
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'shape' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'shape' ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'shape' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'shape' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></a>
        <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) ) : ?>
        <span class="sep"> | </span>
        <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'shape' ), __( '1 Comment', 'shape' ), __( '% Comments', 'shape' ) ); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'shape' ), '<span class="sep"> | </span><span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late to answer but something like this will work if anyone else is interested

```
<p class="postmetadata">

<?php _e('Filed under&#58;','domain'); ?>
 <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by','domain'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?>
 <br/><?php the_tags(__('Tags:','domain'), ', ', '<br />'); ?>
 <?php _e('Posted on:&nbsp;','domain'); ?>
 <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?><br/>?>
 <?php edit_post_link(__('&nbsp;Edit','domain'), __('&nbsp;&#124;','domain'), ''); ?>
</p>
```